# Is "habit of command" equivalent in meaning to "habit of commanding"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Today I came across the emboldened phrase in a text by Bertrand Russell:

> Good political institutions would weaken the impulse toward force and domination in two ways: first, by increasing the opportunities for the creative impulses, and by shaping education so as to strengthen these impulses; secondly, by diminishing the outlets for the possessive instincts. The diffusion of power, both in the political and the economic sphere, instead of its concentration in the hands of officials and captains of industry, would greatly diminish the opportunities for acquiring **the habit of command**, out of which the desire for exercising tyranny is apt to spring.

I expected the author to have used "the habit of commanding" instead, because *the habit of [verb]+ing* is a very common structure. When is it acceptable to use the structure *the habit of [noun]*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is interesting because the sense of *command* in the phrase "the habit of command" isn't quite aligned with any of the noun definitions of *command* that appear in *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2010):

> **command** ... *n.* **1.** The act of commanding. **2.** An order given with authority. **3.** Computers. A signal that initiates an operation defined by an instruction. **4a.** The authority to command: *an admiral in command*. **b.** Possession and exercise of the authority to command: *command of the seas*. **5.** Ability to control or use; mastery: *command of four languages*. **6.** Dominance by location; extent of view. **7a.** The jurisdiction of a commander. **b.** A military unit, post, district, or region under the control of one officer. **c.** A unit of the US Air Force that is larger than an air force.

Several of these definitions (1, 4a, 4b, and 5) come close to expressing the sense of *command* as used in "the habit of command"—but none is quite right. The closest, in my view, are 4b and 5—but even they seem less open ended than the meaning of *command* in the phrase you ask about seems to be. Essentially "the habit of command" amounts to "the habit of deciding and telling others what to do," or more simply "habitual unchallenged authority."

The phrase produces an interesting Ngram chart when tracked for the period 1700–2008:

[image]

This pattern of usage suggests that "the habit of command" is a set phrase, albeit one whose popularity has waned over the past century.

---

***Historical usage of 'the habit of command'***

One early occurrence of the phrase appears in Edward Gibbon, [*The History of the Decline and Fall of the Roman Empire*](https://books.google.com/books?id=r9MLAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA287&dq=%22habit+of+command%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD_7mJuN_XAhUpwVQKHZVnCNcQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22habit%20of%20command%22&f=false), volume 1 (1776):

> The natives of Europe were brave and robust. Spain, Gaul, Britain, and Illyricum supplied the legions with excellent soldiers, and constituted the real strength of the monarchy. Their personal valor remained, but they no longer possessed that public courage which is nourished by the love of independence, the sense of national honor, the presence of danger, and **the habit of command**. They received laws and governors from the will of their sovereign, and trusted for their defence to a mercenary army. The posterity of their boldest leaders was contented with the rank of citizens and subjects. The most aspiring spirits resorted to the court or standard of the emperors; and the deserted provinces, deprived of political strength or union, insensibly sunk into the languid indifference of private life.

Another fairly early instance appears in a [review of *Account of the Right Honourable William Pitt*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-mIoAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA138&dq=%22habit+of+command%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD_7mJuN_XAhUpwVQKHZVnCNcQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22habit%20of%20command%22&f=false), in *The Monthly Magazine* (March 1, 1806):

> This ingenious statesman, as yet uncorrupted with power, and viewing a well-merited renown as the sole reward and only recompence of his virtuous endeavours, boldly, fairly, and honestly entered on a measure, which now served as a spear to probe the character of his political adversaries, and was afterwards employed by the Abdiels who opposed himself to probe his own heart, when it was supposed to have been perverted by the fascinations of office, and **the habit of command**.

A third early and probably quite influential source is William Duane, [*A Hand Book for Infantry: Containing the First Principles of Military Discipline*](https://books.google.com/books?id=SLrFs0D3IFYC&pg=PA11&dq=%22habit+of+command%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv0KO6vd_XAhUJ3WMKHRKnAA84ChDoAQg6MAM#v=onepage&q=%22habit%20of%20command%22&f=false) (1814), which uses the phrase three times:

> No officer can expect to be competent to command a company, much less a regiment, (to which every officer should through merit aspire) unless he has had practical experience; and in no circumstance can an officer as soon acquire **the habit of command**, or learn the mode and effect of discipline, as by personally conducting the drill of 40 to 100 men.
>
> ...
>
> The first lieutenant is to the captain what the lieutenant-colonel and major are to the colonel. He must always consider himself bound to see the duties of the company performed in obedience to the captain, and according to the principles of discipline ; he should aim to excel, as he aspires to a company, and must take charge of it in the absence of the captain. He should practice in the drills constantly, to acquire **the habit of command**, and to be prepared by exercise, and with presence of mind, to correct errors in manœuvres, which he can never do unless he has had practical experience ; and the drill is the best of all schools to acquire **the habit of command**.

Other famous writers who have used the expression include Jeremy Bentham, in [*Constitutional Code*](https://books.google.com/books?id=yFdHAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA134&dq=%22other+part+the+habit+of+command%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2v-nBvN_XAhWmjFQKHS_-DM4Q6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22other%20part%20the%20habit%20of%20command%22&f=false) (1822–1832), which contrasts "the habit of command" with its opposite, the habit of obedience"; James Russell Lowell, "[Slaveholding Territories](https://books.google.com/books?id=4sNqLaJFW2QC&pg=PA74&dq=%22habit+of+command%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6ybflyt_XAhVCxGMKHXQqAkI4HhDoAQgtMAE#v=onepage&q=%22habit%20of%20command%22&f=false)" (April 19, 1849); Matthew Arnold, [*Schools and Universities on the Continent*](https://books.google.com/books?id=eYeBOIvpyH0C&pg=PA112&dq=%22habit+of+command%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-8-XozN_XAhUY6GMKHeClDXs4KBDoAQhbMAk#v=onepage&q=%22habit%20of%20command%22&f=false) (1868/1882); Joseph Conrad, in [*Nostromo*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9IgnCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT231&dq=%22the+long+habit+of+command%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj93YOdy9_XAhUP9mMKHX3iCZUQ6AEIRTAF#v=onepage&q=%22the%20long%20habit%20of%20command%22&f=false) (1904—"Authoritative by temperament and the long habit of command, Captain Mitchell was no democrat."); and Edith Wharton, in [*The Fruit of the Tree*](https://books.google.com/books?id=grOwAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA439&dq=%22renewed+self-confidence+and+the+habit+of+command%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj45YSawt_XAhUFymMKHdRJCWUQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22renewed%20self-confidence%20and%20the%20habit%20of%20command%22&f=false) (1907).

A number of instances of "habit of command" arise in connection with the slave-owning class of U.S. Southern whites in the period before the Civil War—Southern politicians seem to have favored the phrase as an aspect of the supposedly natural system of lordship and bondage that prevailed in that part of the world. For instance a [member of the Virginia House of Delegates](https://books.google.com/books?id=jzRcAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA8&dq=%22habit+of+command%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiugtaDzt_XAhUK6WMKHeONCOE4UBDoAQgnMAA#v=onepage&q=%22habit%20of%20command%22&f=false) uses it in 1832 in connection with the prospect of spontaneous slave revolts, and a ["state chancellor" in South Carolina](https://books.google.com/books?id=3xUAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA15&dq=%22habit+of+command%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6ybflyt_XAhVCxGMKHXQqAkI4HhDoAQhUMAg#v=onepage&q=%22habit%20of%20command%22&f=false) refers to it approvingly in an 1835 oration, as does a [U.S. diplomat from South Carolina](https://books.google.com/books?id=rCY4AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA297&dq=%22habit+of+command%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYr8-40t_XAhXmjFQKHeBGANQQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22habit%20of%20command%22&f=false) in an 1859 oration arguing that "The habit of command, where you have right to obedience [namely from slaves], develops necessarily the habit of considerate courtesy where there is no right to command." As late as July 26, 1876, in a letter to President Ulysses Grant, the [governor of South Carolina](https://books.google.com/books?id=nQstPeWppxsC&pg=PA201&dq=%22habit+of+command%22+Grant&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQloGj1d_XAhXnsFQKHUuGAs4Q6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22habit%20of%20command%22%20Grant&f=false) cites "the long habit of command and self-assertion on the part of whites of these Southern States" as a partial explanation for why they, despite being outnumbered, were able to terrorize their former slaves.

---

***Bertrand Russell's use of 'the habit of command'***

For his part, Bertrand Russell uses the expression "the habit of command" on multiple occasions. From [*Pacifism and Revolution, 1916–18*](https://books.google.com/books?id=67vhSIBLHQUC&pg=PA304&dq=%22habit+of+command%22+Bertrand+Russell&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCn4Xv1t_XAhXlhFQKHanMBdMQ6AEIMjAC#v=onepage&q=%22habit%20of%20command%22%20Bertrand%20Russell&f=false)—the same book from which the OP's example comes:

> It is the growth of habit more than anything else that render most old men useless and even pernicious, because they cannot adapt their thoughts to new conditions. It is the strength of  habitual opinion that makes people unable to accept new truths, however conclusive may be the evidence in their favour. It is **the habit of command**, in those in authority, which makes them become impatient of opposition and prone to punish those who try to warn them against impending errors. In all these ways habits do harm as soon as men become their slaves, and hardly anyone can hope not to be the slave of habit when middle life has been reached.

From [*Political Ideals*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7Q2GAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22habit+of+command%22+Bertrand+Russell&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL9d734N_XAhWnxFQKHZAvBNA4ChDoAQg1MAQ#v=onepage&q=%22habit%20of%20command%22%20Bertrand%20Russell&f=false) (1917):

> The diffusion of power, both in the political and the economic sphere, instead of its concentration in the hands of officials and captains of industry, would greatly diminish the opportunities for acquiring **the habit of command**, out of which the desire for exercising tyranny is apt to spring.

From [*Proposed Roads to Freedom: Socialism, Anarchism and Syndicalism*](https://books.google.com/books?id=U0u6HCt0ebsC&pg=PA144&dq=%22habit+of+command%22+Bertrand+Russell&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCn4Xv1t_XAhXlhFQKHanMBdMQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22habit%20of%20command%22%20Bertrand%20Russell&f=false) (1919):

> Besides these two influences of capitalism in promoting war, there is another, much less emphasized by the critics of capitalism, but by no means less important: I mean the pugnacity which tends to be developed in men who have **the habit of command**. So long as capitalist society persists, an undue measure of power will be in the hands of those who have acquired wealth and influence through a great position in industry or finance. Such men are in the habit, in private life, of finding their will seldom questioned; they are surrounded by obsequious satellites and are not infrequently engaged in conflicts with Trade Unions. Among their friends and acquaintances are included those who hold high positions in government or administration, and these men equally are liable to become autocratic through the habit of giving orders.
>
> ...
>
> In a world where all men and women enjoy economic freedom, there will not be the same **habit of command**, nor, consequently, the same love of despotism; a gentler type of character than that now prevalent will gradually grow up.

From [*The Scientific Outlook*](https://books.google.com/books?id=gq7LDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA9&dq=%22habit+of+command%22+Bertrand+Russell&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCn4Xv1t_XAhXlhFQKHanMBdMQ6AEIQTAF#v=onepage&q=%22habit%20of%20command%22%20Bertrand%20Russell&f=false) (1931):

> The government, being an oligarchy, will instil submissiveness into the great bulk of the population, confining initiative and **the habit of command** to its members.

From [*Power: A New Social Analysis*](https://books.google.com/books?id=pZ7NtoL6_SoC&pg=PA11&dq=%22habit+of+command+makes+it+easier+to+bear%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq4ra_3t_XAhUrjlQKHR7QDdMQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22habit%20of%20command%20makes%20it%20easier%20to%20bear%22&f=false) (1938):

> There is no doubt that **the habit of command** makes it easier to bear responsibilities and to take quick decisions. A clan which follows its hereditary chief probably does better than if it chose its chief by lot. On the other hand, a body like the mediaeval church, which chose its chief on account of conspicuous merits, and usually after he had had considerable experience of important administrative posts, secured, on average, considerably better results than were secured, in the same period, in hereditary monarchies.

---

***Conclusion***

For Russell, it seems clear, "the habit of command" doesn't mean simply "the tendency to issue commands"; rather, it refers to an attitude or mindset in which one's right to command others has become second nature, through proclivity, real-world experience, and social or hierarchical advantage. Russell is far from the first person to use the phrase in this way. Perhaps, at some point in its development, "the habit of command" might have been functionally interchangeable with "the habit of commanding"; but today, "the habit of command" exists in English as a set phrase with its own history, associations, and meaning.